How to fix InvalidRequestError: The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated, learn more here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations
I am making a PDF chatbot using openai and langchain, I am facing this
InvalidRequestError: The model text-davinci-003 has been deprecated, learn more here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations error and I have no idea how to fix it, I am still very new to all of this.
This is my code below
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import ElasticVectorSearch, Pinecone, Weaviate, FAISS
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "API KEY"
pdfs_folder = 'PDFs/'
pdf_files = [file for file in os.listdir(pdfs_folder) if file.endswith('.pdf')]
raw_text = ''
# Iterate through each PDF file
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    # Construct the path to the PDF file
    pdf_path = os.path.join(pdfs_folder, pdf_file)
    # Read the PDF file
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(file)
        
        # Extract raw text from pages
        for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
            text = page.extract_text()
            if text:
                raw_text += text
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(        
    separator = "\n",
    chunk_size = 500,
    chunk_overlap  = 200,
    length_function = len,
)
chunks = text_splitter.split_text(raw_text)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
docsearch = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embeddings)
chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff")
query = "What are the core values of JM Finance?"
docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)

I am using a notebook for this
I am getting error in this line: chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
I would really appreciate if someone can help or teach me how to change the model

Does this answer your question? OpenAI API error: "The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated"

I slightly modified your code with corrected lib and removing unused ones
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
# from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
# from langchain.vectorstores import ElasticVectorSearch, Pinecone, Weaviate, FAISS
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

pdfs_folder = 'PDFs/'
pdf_files = [file for file in os.listdir(pdfs_folder) if file.endswith('.pdf')]
raw_text = ''
# Iterate through each PDF file
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    # Construct the path to the PDF file
    pdf_path = os.path.join(pdfs_folder, pdf_file)
    # Read the PDF file
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(file)
        # Extract raw text from pages
        for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
            text = page.extract_text()
            if text:
                raw_text += text
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
    separator = "\n",
    chunk_size = 500,
    chunk_overlap  = 200,
    length_function = len,
)

chunks = text_splitter.split_text(raw_text)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
docsearch = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embeddings)

from langchain_openai import OpenAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff")
query = "What are the core values of JM Finance?"
docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
print(chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query))

